# calculating the position of a given digit in a constant (e.g. $\pi$)

Tags: constants

I'm aware that there are a lot BBP type formulas out there which extract the n-th digit of the  observed constant.

I'm asking for the reverse action, namely, is it possible to find the first occurrence of a given digit (or string of digits) within a constant? If not, any related work, analysis and other hints are welcome.

Comment: Have fun with http://www.angio.net/pi/piquery.html. Search for your birthday and read "How the Pi-Searcher Works" in that page.

Comment: If you came up with a formula for it you would be famous... at least on math.stackexchange :)  You should do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no good way to determine the first occurrence of a string of digits within $\pi$. In fact, we do not know whether every finite string of digits actually occurs in $\pi$. [We believe this is true, but we do not know how to show it].

For some particular constants, it's rather easy. For instance, perhaps the simplest normal number is the number $0.12345678910111213\ldots$, formed by concatenating all base $10$ digits together. It should be pretty easy to determine the first occurrence of a string of digits here, but this is a very contrived example.